# Display not correctly formatted when the paragraph is only a few words (less than an entire line)

Tags: html, css

I have an html page for displaying comments. Everything is ok when the comment exceed one line. When comment is less than one line, I have a formatting problem. See the example in the jsfiddle below to understand.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ajNJf/

I have 4 comments from Johnny, Mike, Stevie, Michael. The comment from Stevie (the third) is only a few words. This causes my formatting to break.

Any idea how to arrange my css to solve this?

Below is the code:

```
            <h3>Comments <span class="comments-amount">(89)</span></h3>

            <div class="comments-sec">

                <ol class="commentlist">

                    <li>
                        <div class="comments">
                            <div class="avatar"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?d=mm&s=50" alt="" border="0" /> </div>
                            <div class="comment-des">
                            <div class="comment-by"><strong>Johnny</strong><span class="reply"><span style="color:#aaa">/ </span><a href="#">Reply</a></span> <span class="date">June 1, 2012</span></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="comments">
                            <div class="avatar"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?d=mm&s=50" alt="" border="0" /> </div>
                            <div class="comment-des">
                            <div class="comment-by"><strong>Mike</strong><span class="reply"><span style="color:#aaa">/ </span><a href="#">Reply</a></span> <span class="date">June 1, 2012</span></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="comments">
                            <div class="avatar"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?d=mm&s=50" alt="" border="0" /> </div>
                            <div class="comment-des">
                            <div class="comment-by"><strong>Stevie</strong><span class="reply"><span style="color:#aaa">/ </span><a href="#">Reply</a></span> <span class="date">June 1, 2012</span></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="comments">
                            <div class="avatar"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/00000000000000000000000000000000?d=mm&s=50" alt="" border="0" /> </div>
                            <div class="comment-des">
                            <div class="comment-by"><strong>Michael</strong><span class="reply"><span style="color:#aaa">/ </span><a href="#">Reply</a></span> <span class="date">June 1, 2012</span></div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    </ol>

            </div>
```

And the css

```
.comments-sec {
    float:left;
width:100%;
line-height: 20px;
}  

ol.commentlist {
float:left; 
width:100%;
margin: 0;
}

ol.commentlist li {
float:left;
border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
padding: 25px 15px 20px 15px;
}

ol.commentlist li:first-child {
border:none;
padding: 25px 15px 0px 15px;
}

ol.commentlist li {list-style: none;}

ol li ol.childlist{
float:right;
width:89%;
margin:0px;
}

ol.commentlist li ol.childlist li:first-child {
border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
padding: 25px 0 0 0;
font-size: 12px;
}

ol.commentlist li ol.childlist li {
border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
margin:25px 0 15px 0;
font-size: 12px;
}

.comments {
float:left;
width:100%;
}

.comments-amount {color: #888;}

ol li ol.childlist .comment-des {
float:right; 
width:89%;
}

.avatar {float:left}

.comment-des{
float:right;
width:90%;
}

.comment-des strong {
float:left;
padding-right:5px;
font-size:12px;
} 
.comment-des span {
float:left;
color:#888;
}

.comment-by {
float:left;
width:100%;
padding-bottom:8px;
padding-top:5px;
color: #000;
}

.ie7 .comment-by span.reply span {display: none;}

.comment-by span.reply {
color:#888; 
float:right;    display: inline;
}

.comment-by span.reply a {
float: right;
height: 17px;
margin-left: 5px;
font-weight: normal;
float:right;

}

.comment-by span.date {
color:#888;
padding-right: 7px; 
float: right;
}

.ie7 .comment-by .date {display: none;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: “Not correctly formatted” is not a problem description. Specify the expected rendering and how the actual rendering differs from it.

Comment: IMHO..Your whole css needs to be re-coded.. You could do this better and simpler without any floats at all.. using relative and absolute positions.

Comment: My version [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/4Hu74/) Pretty much the same, just a little tidier and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove float left from following

```
ol.commentlist li {
  border-top: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
  float: left; //remove it
  padding: 25px 15px 20px; //change padding right 1% left 1%
}
```

add width 98% and approprate padding. and you are done

```
ol.commentlist li {
  width: 98%;
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but this adds other problems, for example the lines between each comment is no more correctly positionned.

Comment: please chek the edited one, avatar and commentproper spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem you mentioned, not only exists for one liner but also for paragraph on lower width screens

add `width` to `avatar` class and then give some margin between the 2 `div`

```
.avatar {
      float:left;
      width:10%;
 }

.comment-des{
    float:right;
    width:88%;
    margin-left:2%
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ajNJf/4/)

**Alternatively,** since you have used `:first-child`, i assume `css3` is an option, then, rather go for `display:table` rather than `float`ing

```
   .comments {
        display:table; /* added */
        width:100%;
   }
   ol li ol.childlist .comment-des { /* this is not required */

   }
   .avatar {
       display:table-cell;/* added */
       width:10%;
       vertical-align:top;/* added -display image at the top of div */
   }
   .comment-des {
       display:table-cell;/* added */
       float:right;/* added - to cope with one-liners */
       min-width:90%;
       border:1px solid red; /* just for demo*/
   }
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ajNJf/8/)

Comment: Your demo is the broken one.

Comment: You updated it now. It works but before it didn't the text was still over to the side. Oh the first one still doesn't, thats the one with the text over the side.

Comment: @Ruddy : tahts because it has to adjust according to the `margin` for different screen sizes, taht why i gave an alternate solution....but OP already accepted an answer, so never mind....gud morning fella!! :)